# How to resolve “A cursor with the name already exists” error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created a cursor in a stored procedure and in that cursor I call another stored procedure.

In that stored procedure, I have created another cursor with the same name.

While running the main stored procedure, I get an error

> A cursor with the name already exists

I am confused that I have created cursor with same but in two different stored procedures, then why is this error thrown?

Comment: Why so many Cursors in the first place? Why not a set based method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some research I have found its root cause.

When declare cursor I have not specified that the scope of the cursor is local to the batch. And I have checked my database properties where cursor default scope is set as **GLOBAL**, because of this I have gotten this error while running stored procedure.

So to resolve this error there are two options:

1. Define a local cursor. Just put the keyword **LOCAL** after CURSOR:

   ```
    declare MyCursor CURSOR LOCAL FOR
    ...
   ```
2. Define Default scope of courser as **LOCAL** for database.

   Database > Right Click > Properties

[image]

Comment: I suggest option 1 so that the code will run as desired regardless of database setting.